# Prove that $a^{4b}+b^{4a}\geq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, exponentiation

Inspired by a problem of [Vasile Cirtoaje](https://www.emis.de/journals/TJNSA/article/Vol%204%20no%202/Vol4_No2_130-137_PROOFS%20OF%20THREE%20OPEN%20INEQUALITIES%20WITH%20....pdf) I propose this :

> Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
>   $$a^{4b}+b^{4a}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

I compute the derivative of $f(x)=x^{4(1-x)}+(1-x)^{4x}$ on $]0,1]$ we get :
$$ f'(x)=x^{4 (1 - x)} (\frac{4 (1 - x)}{x} - 4 \log(x)) + (1 - x)^{(4 x)} (4 \log(1 - x) - \frac{4 x}{1 - x})$$

If we denote by $g(x)$ the function :

$$g(x)=x^{4 (1 - x)} (\frac{4 (1 - x)}{x} - 4 \log(x))$$

We can rewrite the derivative as :

$$f'(x)=g(x)-g(1-x)$$

So it's remains to show that $g(x)\geq g(1-x)$ or $g(x)\leq g(1-x)$

So it remains to show that $g(x)$ is increasing or decreasing .

After that I'm stuck...

Any helps are very appreciated !

Thanks a lot for your time .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Alternative Proof*:

We need to prove that, for all $a$ in $(0, 1/2]$,
$$a^{4 - 4a} + (1 - a)^{4a} \ge 1/2.$$

We split into two cases:

---

**Case I** $\,\, a\in (0, 1/4)$:

We have
$$a^{4 - 4a} + (1 - a)^{4a}
\ge (1 - a)^{4a} \ge 1 - a > \frac12.$$

---

**Case II** $\,\,a \in [1/4, 1/2]$:

First, using Bernoulli inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 a^{4 - 4a} 
 &= 2^{-1}2^{-(2 - 4a)}(1 - (1 - 2a))^{3 - 4a} a\\
 &\ge 2^{-1}2^{-(2 - 4a)}[1 - (1 - 2a)(3 - 4a)] a\\
 &\ge 2^{-1}[1 - (2 - 4a)\ln 2]\,[1 - (1 - 2a)(3 - 4a)]a
\end{align*}
where we have used $2^{-(2 - 4a)} = \mathrm{e}^{-(2 - 4a)\ln 2}
\ge 1 - (2 - 4a)\ln 2$.

Second, using Bernoulli inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 (1 - a)^{4a} &= 2^{-2}2^{2 - 4a}(1 + (1 - 2a))^{4a}\\
 &\ge 2^{-2}2^{2 - 4a}[1 + (1 - 2a)\cdot 4a]\\
 &\ge 2^{-2}[1 + (2 - 4a)\ln 2]\,[1 + (1 - 2a)\cdot 4a]
\end{align*}
where we have used $2^{2 - 4a} = \mathrm{e}^{(2 - 4a)\ln 2}
\ge 1 + (2 - 4a)\ln 2$.

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &2^{-1}[1 - (2 - 4a)\ln 2]\,[1 - (1 - 2a)(3 - 4a)]a\\
 &\quad + 2^{-2}[1 + (2 - 4a)\ln 2]\,[1 + (1 - 2a)\cdot 4a] \ge \frac12
\end{align*}
or
$$ (1 - 2a)^2[-16(\ln 2)a^2 + (20\ln 2 - 4)a + 2\ln 2 - 1]
\ge 0$$
which is true.

---

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative proof*:

I give a proof following @Malper's nice idea.

---

*Fact 1*: Let $x\in (0, 1/2]$ and $t \in (0, 1/2]$. Then $x^{4 - 4t} + (1 - x)^{4t} \ge \frac12$.
The proof is given at the end.

By Fact 1, we have
$x^{4 - 4x} + (1 - x)^{4x} \ge \frac12$
for all $x$ in $(0, 1/2]$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*: Let $f(x, t) = x^{4 - 4t} + (1 - x)^{4t}$. We have
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
 &= 4(1 - x)^{4t}\ln (1 - x) - 4x^{4 - 4t}\ln x\\
 &= 4x^{-4t}\Big([x(1 - x)]^{4t}\ln(1 - x) - x^4\ln x\Big)\\
 &\le 4x^{-4t}\Big([x(1 - x)]^{4\cdot \frac12}\ln(1 - x) - x^4\ln x\Big)\\
 &= 4x^{2 - 4t}\Big((1 - x)^2\ln(1 - x) - x^2\ln x\Big)\\
 &\le 0
\end{align}
where we have used $(1 - x)^2\ln(1 - x) - x^2\ln x \le 0$.
*Note*: Let $g(x) = (1 - x)^2\ln(1 - x) - x^2\ln x$. We have $g''(x) = 2\ln(1 - x) - 2\ln x \ge 0$ on $(0, 1/2]$. Thus, $g(x)$ is convex on $(0, 1/2]$. Also, $g(0^{+}) = 0$ and $g(1/2) = 0$. Thus, $g(x) \le 0$ on $(0, 1/2]$.

Thus, we have $f(x, t) \ge f(x, 1/2) = x^2 + (1 - x)^2 \ge 1/2$.

We are done.