# Maximize $x^{2(1-x)^2}+(1-x)^{2x^2}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

It's a problem of mine :

> Let $0<x<1$ and defines the function :
> $$f(x)=x^{2(1-x)^2}+(1-x)^{2x^2}$$
> We call this function the Napoleon's hat. Now we want to know the maximal height of Napoleon's hat on $[0,1]$. I suspect that the value is $\sqrt{2}$ at $x=0.5$ .

The expression of the derivative is :
$$f'(x)= x^{2 (1 - x)^2} \left(\frac{2 (1 - x)^2}{x} - 4 (1 - x) \log(x)\right) + (1 - x)^{2 x^2} \left(4 x \log(1 - x) - \frac{2 x^2}{(1 - x)}\right)$$

My question :

Can someone show that the maximal value is $\sqrt{2}$ at $x=0.5$ ?

Comment: Well, the function **is** symmetric about $x=\frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: I can only suggest to analyze instead $\ln f(x)$. It should have the same maximum point. It is easier to differentiate.

Comment: @kolobokish: is it ? $(\ln f(x))'=f'(x)/f(x).$

Comment: Don't think like that. Just take log and differentiate. Do not refer back to $f(x)$.

Comment: What is your question ? To compute $f(\frac12)$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think I found the solution in my way.

Comment: Ah sorry. I thought it was product.

Comment: @kolobokish: this is why I told you that you didn't pay attention. But you didn't pay attention. :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Really)). I thought it was product. Sorry. But the idea remains the same for this from of derivative. First note that $f'(\frac{1}{2})=0$, then look at the cases $x\in (0, \frac{1}{2})$. And compare $x^{2(1-x)^2}$ with $(1-x)^{2x^2}$. And the others respectively, having in mind $1-x > x$.

Comment: @kolobokish: why do you tell me ? By the way, there is no need to compute $f'(1/2)$, you know upfront that it is zero. It is more important to check non-existence of other roots.

Comment: Well, clearly $f(x)=f(1-x)$, which means that function is symmetric with respect to $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore if we will show that function is increasing on interval $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, then maximum of this function is when $x=\frac{1}{2}$. So at this point you need to prove that $f'(x)\ge0$ on interval $(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: As you see in similar problems e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496475/prove-that-a4bb4a-geq-frac12, one approach is to use bounds for each term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g(x)=x^{2(1-x)^2}$ and $h(x)=-(1-x)^{2x^2}$, so that $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$. As Daniyar Aubekerov commented, it suffices to show that $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$, which is equivalent to showing that $g'(x)>h'(x)$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$. We have
\begin{align*}
g'(x) &= 2 (1-x) x^{2(1-x)^2-1} (1-x-2 x \log x) \\
h'(x) &= 2 x (1-x)^{2 x^2-1} (x-2 (1-x) \log (1-x),
\end{align*}
each factor of which is positive; therefore it suffices to show that their quotient $g'(x)/h'(x)$ is greater than $1$. Define
\begin{align*}
a(x) &= (1-x^2) \log (1-x)+(x-2) x \log x \\
b(x) &= \frac{1-x-2 x \log x}{x-2 (1-x) \log (1-x)},
\end{align*}
so that $g'(x)/h'(x) = e^{2a(x)}b(x)$; it suffices to show that $a(x) > 0$ and $b(x) > 1$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$.

*Showing $a(x)>0$:* It is easy to check that $a'''(x) > 0$ for $x\in(0,\frac12]$ and that $a''(\frac12)=0$. Therefore $a''(x)<0$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$, and hence $a(x)$ is concave on $(0,\frac12)$. Since $a(0)=a(\frac12)=0$, it follows that $a(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$.

*Showing $b(x)>1$:* If we further define $c(x) = 1-x-2 x \log x$ and $d(x) = x-2 (1-x) \log (1-x)$, so that $b(x) = c(x)/d(x)$, it suffices to show that $c(x) - d(x) > 0$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$. But it is easy to check that $c''(x)-d''(x)<0$ for $x\in(0,\frac12)$ and hence that $c(x)-d(x)$ is concave on $(0,\frac12)$; since $c(0)-d(0)=1$ and $c(\frac12)-d(\frac12)=0$, the difference $c(x)-d(x)$ is positive for $x\in(0,\frac12$).

Comment: It is a very nice solution. (+1)

Comment: Awesome!Definitely my answer !