# Find all the values of $a$ such $x^{ay}+y^{ax}>1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> Find all the values of $a$ such that $x^{ay}+y^{ax}>1$ holds for all $x, y \in (0, 1)$.

> (Original Text) for any postive real number $1>x,y>0$, find the  all value $a$ such $$x^{ay}+y^{ax}>1$$

I have know $a=1$ is hold,because
$$x^y=\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1-x}{x}}\right)^y>\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1-x}{x}y}=\dfrac{x}{x+y-xy}>\dfrac{x}{x+y}$$
and
$$y^x>\dfrac{y}{x+y}$$
so we have
$$x^y+y^x>\dfrac{x}{x+y}+\dfrac{y}{x+y}=1$$

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your question. At the top it says "find the all value $a$ such", which I think you mean "find all the values of $a$ such that", but at the bottom it says "$a$ maximum of the value" so do you want all the possible values of $a$ or the maximum value?

Comment: You [forgot](http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf) to [mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) that $y\in[0,1]$ (for the 1st half).

Comment: Linking another related, interesting and [unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496475/prove-that-a4bb4a-geq-frac12) ...

Comment: @inequality I edited the question. Is it OK?